# how to target or select a frame in IE developer toolbar while analysing multi frame page?

Tags: html, web-developer-toolbar

If a page has multiframes & multiple pages are loaded how to select a particulart frame page to debug or see the html source through IE Developer tool.

I need this for running a jquery script using the console tab, against particular page in a frame how to do that in IE developer toolbar.

Regards,
Umesh V